# How to use javaScript classes without constructor in WebStorm with Babel?

Tags: javascript, class, webstorm, babeljs

This code work in  http://jsbin.com (ES6/Babel)

```
 class Human {
    gender = 'male';
    prnG = ()=> {
        console.log(this.gender)
    }
}

class Person extends Human {
    name = 'Ana';
    gender = 'female';
    prnN = ()=> {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}

const hum = new Human();
hum.prnG(); // "male"

const person = new Person();
person.prnG(); // "female"
person.prnN(); // "Ana"
```

How to use classes without constructor in WebStorm with Babel settings to transform in ES6 with constuctor and property (this.gender = 'male')?

Comment: use this plugin for babel https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Answer (score 1):

You need [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) Babel plugin for this.

- `npm i babel-plugin-transform-class-properties babel-preset-env --save-dev`
- in `.babelrc`:

{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "env"
  ]
}